# i have "cannot resolve symbol 'action_add_item"

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i have "cannot resolve symbol 'action_add_item' in my code i don't know why.

I follow this video on youtube to make a totolist in android studio 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JXFZ52IIl0A

here's the code

```
         @Override
         public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {
           switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.action_add_item:
            final EditText itemEditText = new EditText(this);
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    builder.setTitle("Add New Task")
                    .setMessage("What do you want to do next?")
                    .setView(itemEditText)
                    .setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            String task = String.valueOf(itemEditText.getText());
                            dbHelper.insertNewItem(item);
                            showItemList();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel",null);
                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
            return true;
      } 
      return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

sorry if not clear or what, first time i ask something on stackoverflow.

Comment: What issue are you facing ?@SendoTks

Comment: Is it `Aler    tDialog dialog= new AlertDialog.Builder(this)` just a copy paste problem?
`

Comment: Yes just copy past problem in my question, i did it good in my code

Comment: @Abhishekkumar it dosen't run, i've an error "cannot resolve symbol 'action_add_item" i don't know how to fix it, it's the same code than in the video i've shared, i don't understand how can i fix it it's the only error but can't run because of this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The video is incomplete. You need to have a menu.xml file in order for the menu options to work correctly. When the user selects an item from the options menu (including action items in the app bar), the system calls your activity's onOptionsItemSelected() method. This method passes the MenuItem selected. Which in your case is `action_add_item`

Your menu.xml should look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_add_item"
          android:title="ADD ITEM"
</menu>
```

Comment: Juste copy past problem when i post my question, it's already like that in my code

Comment: Check out the updated answer

Comment: like that ? i've edited my question, trying to do like u said, still have the error "Error:(69, 22) error: cannot find symbol variable action_add_item"

Comment: Why are you even using switch case when you have only one case? Are you sure the id of the element is action_add_item?

Comment: Like i said i just follow a youtube tutorial, it work on the tutorial video i've do the exactly same this is why i don't understand why it dosen't work for me

Comment: Well do you have a layout? An xml file? Is there anything labeled with an id of action_add_item? I'll watch the video and try to figure out what's wrong

Comment: Yes i have activity_main.xlm and row.xml with the exactlry same content than the video, i've menu.xlm who is empty because she dosen't show it on the video, maybe it's important to make it work ? i've only one error this is for the action_add_item

Comment: Ok check the edited answer. I figured out what was wrong

Comment: It fix the error, thank you a lot,  it compile but the app crash immediatly on my phone, i'm gonna try another phone, if it still crash at launch i'll search why

Comment: You're welcome. Consider marking the answer as correct? Read more about how to do that here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Ok the app crash immadiatly after in run it, i don't think i'm gonna find how, it look like you know this langage have you a tutorial of whatever to suggest me ? i've to do a todolist app on in java android.

Comment: Can you post the logs? Connect your phone to android studio and then run the app. Open Logcat in android studio (while the phone is connected) and then post the error that caused the app to crash. usually in red

Comment: ho nice i've found the problem with the logcat, thank you again you save my life !
i've juste commented thoses lines
//icon.mutate();
//            icon.setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

Comment: You're so very welcome! :)